# Replace min & max value in a list

Tags: python, list

I need help to write a python function for lists that will do two things.

First instance, it will replace the largest and smallest elements in the list with the number 5000 (for largest) and -5000 (for smallest).

```
thelist = input("Please input a list with numbers: ")
mylist = list(map(int, thelist.split()))
```

Please input a list with numbers: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

```
print(mylist)
```

Result: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

Honestly I have no clue how to replace the 1 and 10 with the numbers 5000 and -5000 using a py function. I can get the min and max number but replacing them is something I don't know how to do.

Comment: `mylist[0]` and `mylist[10]` will let you access the first and last members of the list. `len(mylist)` will give you the length of the list.

Answer (score 5):

In a bit condensed format using list comprehension, You can use

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
b = [-5000 if x == min(a) else 5000 if x == max(a) else x for x in a]
```

It replaces the minimal elements by -5000 and the maximal ones by 5000. f there are several minimal values, all of them will be replaced. You can use a function to use other values than -5000, 5000.

Answer (score 3):

```
mylist[mylist.index(min(mylist))] = -5000
mylist[mylist.index(max(mylist))] = 5000
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by two phases over min/max:

```
arr = [1,2,3,4]
arr[arr.index(max(arr))] = 5000
```

This yields:

> [1, 2, 3, 5000]

The two phases here are:

1. Find the max value: `max(arr)`. In this example, the value will be 4.
2. Find the index of max value: `arr.index(4)`. In this example, the index will be 3.

The two phases lead to assignment at the index at the max value cell. Note that this assumes a unique max value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mylist[0] = -5000` and `mylist[-1] = 5000`.

The negative index counts from the right side of the list

Or if your list is jumbled

Try this,

```py
min_pos = mylist.index(min(mylist))
max_pos = mylist.index(max(mylist))

mylist[min_pos] = -5000
mylist[max_pos] = 5000

print(mylist)
```

Hope this answers your question

Answer (score 0):

min_number = mylist.index(min(number_lists))
max_number = mylist.index(max(number_lists))
mylist[min_number] , number_lists[max_number] = mylist[max_number],number_lists[min_number]

Comment: Hello, please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help Thanks!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).